# GSview in apt-get?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, eps

I am trying to search GSview in Linux, but I cannot find it by `apt-cache search gsview`.

---

How can you install gsview in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Is `sudo apt-get install gv` what you want?

Comment: @Zacharee1 Please, make your comment an answer. I think it is very good when it is not scaling automatically. I am going to test next it with different test signals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no package called `gsview`, so you're not going to find it by searching that way. There is another package that serves the same function as GSView, called `gv`.

Install it by running `sudo apt-get install gv`.

Answer (score 1):

I did `sudo apt-get install gv` and installed GSView 3.7.4 which is relatively old version. So what I managed to do is to install Ghostscrip 9.21 and GSView 5.0 on wine 64bit version and works perfectly well.

Comment: Confirm that `apt` has 3.7.4.1 version. Which are reasons you need the newer `gv`? - - Can you please give  source which states that the `gv` is outdated in Linux in comparison to Windows? Maybe, we can send an email to the maintainer of Linux `gv` and ask for an update.